# Efficiently tracking first and second click Java - 2d array gui

Tags: java, click, jbutton, actionlistener

I am searching for a more efficient way of tracking the first and second click. Developing a board game and the way I have things working now I dont feel I can add all of the requirements in

Here is how I track clicks at the moment.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
     for(int row = 0; row < boardGame.length; row++){   
     for(int col = 0; col < boardGame.length; col++){
        if(ae.getSource() == boardGame[row][col]){
           if(isFirstClick){                                   
              fromRow = boardGame[row][col].getRow();
              fromCol = boardGame[row][col].getCol();
              this.checkTurn();
              System.out.println(boardGame[row][col].getPlayer());
              isFirstClick = false;
              }// end if
           else {
              toRow = boardGame[row][col].getRow();
              toCol = boardGame[row][col].getCol();
              movePiece();
              isFirstClick = true;
              createBoard();
           }// end else
        }// end get source
    }//end col
  } //end row   
}
```

So while this works for the functionality I have at the moment.. I cant seem to get it to work with move validation. Is there a better way to get the first and second click?

Comment: You should take a look at [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your game looks like chess. I would suggest you to look at **Command** pattern. Every time a user clicks on your board or on some cell on your board or whatever you generate a new event that is transformed into a command that is store it in a list or queue for example. Then you will always know how many clicks and other actions were made and when. Moreover you will able to implement the functionality like **cancel** moves.

These is an example that reveals my idea:

```
static abstract class Event {

}

static class CellClicked extends Event {
    int userId;
    int row;
    int col;
}

static abstract class Command {
    void execute();
}

static class MovePieceCommand extends Command {
    //... implementation    
}

static class SelectPieceCommand extends Command {
    //... implementation
}

static class EventHandler {

    void handle(Event event) {
        //..
    }
}
```

Your **events** are transformed into **commands** by **event listeners**. **Commands** are executed and implement the business logic of your game inside.